# Guardar doc enviado por mail creado mediante script en unidad compartida

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive

He creado una función en script para que cuando un usuario rellene un form, las respuestas vayan a un spreadsheet, se genere una macro (en script) que envié un doc attached en un mail al usuario con unos datos específicos. Este documento lo puedo guardar en mi Drive personal pero necesitaría guardarlo en una unidad compartida. ¿Existe esa posibilidad?

Dejo aquí el código para ver si a alguno se le ocurre.

```js
var FOLDER_NAME = 'Consulta_Fichero_Usuarios';
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(FOLDER_NAME);
folder.next().addFile(file); //Lo añade a la carpeta especificada
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file); //Elimina el archivo de donde venía
```

Comment: Stacksnippet sólo debe usarse para código HTML/CSS/JavaScript que sea ejecutable en este sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive no tiene unidades compartidas en el sentido de las unidades compartidas de Windows y otras plataformas. Podría ser una carpeta compartida o una unidad de equipo que en inglés son llamadas "team drives".

Notas:

1. Las unidades de equipo sólo están disponibles para ser creadas por cuentas de G Suite que tengan dicha posibilidad habilitada.
2. Algunas operaciones con unidades de equipo requieren el uso del [servicio avanzado de Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) (página enlazada en inglés).

El script incluido ya coloca el archivo en una carpeta. Si esa carpeta estuviera compartida ya podrías tener lo que estás buscando, y si a lo que te refieres es usar una carpeta en una unidad de equipo el mismo script te podría servir.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Rubén. Efectivamente, como indicas al final, hacía referencia a una unidad de equipo. Gracias nuevamente.